# Matplotlib setting xlabels

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I'm having trouble setting the x/ylabel for my matplotlib plot, which is using data from a sql query.

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyodbc
import pandas

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=servername;DATABASE=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;')

sql = pandas.read_sql(('SELECT COUNT(Person) AS Cnt, BirthMonth FROM Person GROUP BY BirthMonth'),conn)

df = pandas.DataFrame(sql, columns = ['Cnt', 'BirthMonth'])


ax = df.plot(kind='bar', title = "BirthMonthCounts",figsize=(15,10),legend=False, fontsize=12, x='BirthMonth', y='Cnt', xticks='BirthMonth')
ax.set_xlabel("X",fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("Y",fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

When I run my code the chart displays with the correct values, but without x or ylabels.

I've tried a couple of things, but I suspect I've just written my plot code badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the argument `ax` to `df.plot`,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, title="BirthMonthCounts", figsize=(15,10), legend=False, fontsize=12, x='BirthMonth', y='Cnt', xticks='BirthMonth')
```